# Add a minus into superscript in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I wanted to add a symbol of minus into superscript in gnuplot, like displaying the title "NH4-", I tried the code below, but the minus is too small to see it.

```
set key at 97,19 title "NH_@4^-"
```

then I used these the symbol of "—", but it couldn't display on the map.

```
set key at 97,19 title "NH_@4^—"
```

Comment: Try to use `@` symbol before `_`.

Comment: It couldn't work, but still thank you for your advice@GRSousaJr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can often specify a font or fontsize or fontsize-multiplier. Try

```
 title "NH_@4^{/*1.6 -}"
```

which multiplies the fontsize by 1.6. Note the space between the multiplier and the minus character.

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew "multiplies the fontsize". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some more possibilities:

```
pl 1-x t "1 NH_@4^-",\
   2-x t "2 NH_@4^{--}",\
   3-x t "3 NH_@4^{/=14 -}",\
   4-x t "4 NH_@4^{/Symbol -}",\
   5-x t "5 NH_@4^{\257}"
```

[image]

The look of option 4 and 5 will depend on your terminal (here `set term wxt`).
On other terminal the ascii code might be different.

Answer (score 0):

There is a unicode character  U+207B SUPERSCRIPT MINUS
that would do perfectly for what you want.
This can be entered directly in the text label if you are working in UTF-8, which is highly recommended. Otherwise you can use octal escapes to enter it byte-by-byte:

C octal escaped UTF-8: \342\201\273

```
  set title "NH@^⁻_4"
```

Or in version 5.4 (-rc1 available for testing) you can use a unicode escape sequence

```
  set title "NH@^{\U+207B}_4"
```

[image]

Comment: Note: Are you sure you don't want  NH₄⁺ ?    The superscript + is unicode U+207A

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with it. This is very thoughtful of you. I tried your method in the UTF8 file, but it displays NH^{U+207B}_4 on the map.